# How can I solve the syntax error in loop in Ocaml?

Tags: iteration, syntax-error, ocaml

I am learning Ocaml and trying to practice some codes. In this case, I want to produce a code that applies a function repeatedly n times so it goes as f(f(f(....f(f(x)). When n is 0, this will become an identity function. However, when I try the next case, it keeps saying there is a syntax error on the last of my code underlining 'done'

```
let iter : int * (int -> int) -> (int -> int)
= fun (n, f) -> 
match n with
|0 -> x
|_ -> f c in
        for b = n downto 0 do
          let c = iter x
        done;;
```

What is wrong with my loop? & I wonder as I intended if it would work when my loop is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple errors in the code. First if you use recursion you should be using `let rec`. Next, if you recurse you need to call `iter` with the argument set to `n-1` and there is no need for a `for` loop. If you do use the for loop there is no need to call `iter` recursively.

The following seems to work:

```
let rec iter : int * (int -> int) -> (int -> int) =
fun (n, f) ->
  match n with
  | 0 -> f
  | _ -> fun x -> f ( iter (n-1, f) x )

(* let's use the sqr function as an example *)
let sqr = fun x -> x*x

(* iter(0, sqr) = sqr,  iter(1, sqr) = sqr sqr, iter(2, sqr) = sqr sqr sqr *)
(* So f(2) = sqr(sqr(sqr 2)) = 256 *)

let f = iter (2, sqr)

let _ = print_int ( f 2 )
```

Also note that the `iter` function returns a new *function*, so returning a value does not make sense.

#### For completeness, here's the iterative solution (not recommended) using a `for` loop

```
let rec iter : int * (int -> int) -> (int -> int) =
fun (n, f) ->
  match n with
  | 0 -> f
  | _ -> fun x ->
           let result = ref (f x)   in
           for c = n downto 1 do
             result := f !result
           done;
           !result
```

This version mutates the `result` variable. `result` is reference whose value is read using `!result` and written using `result :=`.

*Disclaimer:* I'm not an ocaml expert so the above could probably be improved.

Comment: Thanks for your help but can I ask one more?
What if I want to get 'x' as a return in case 'n' match with 0? Should there be more argument? I mean I want iteration to start from when 'n' is 1. like |1 -> f

Comment: You need to decide what `iter` should do. They you have defined it (and I have followed) is that `iter` returns a function. Thus the `-> (int -> int)` signature suffix. Is that what you want or do you want `iter` to return a *value*?

Comment: |0 -> fun x -> x give me what I want. What you meant that iter returns a function gave me a hint. Thanks!